# TabActivity tabs are not shown in front

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Tab Layout. When I start my TabActivity the tabs are shown in background and not on top. Why is that so ?

TabsActivity :

```
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabactivity);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();       

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("ABC").setContent(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("DEF").setContent(new Intent(this, Support.class)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("GHI").setContent(new Intent(this, EmailActivity.class)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("TV Survey").setContent(new Intent(this, JKL.class)));

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

tabsactivity.xml

```
<TabHost  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of your problem? it can make it easy to understand the problem much more

Comment: your tabContent is above tabs, thats the reason. Try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_above="id/tabs" for frameLayout